# Issue with a char variable

Tags: c, while-loop, char

When I execute the program down below, where it's explicitly required to type a character different from 'c' or 'n', it is like the character `c` in the while loop condition is a different one from the one in the scanf.

The loop keeps going on no matter what character you type and I want to know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c;
    printf ("type any character except 'c' or 'n': ");
    scanf ("%c%*c", &c);
    while (c != 's' || c != 'n'){
        printf ("\ntype any character except 'c' or 'n': ");
        scanf ("%c%*c", &c);    
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (c != 's' || c != 'n'){` --> `while (c != 'c' && c != 'n'){`

Comment: @Jordi García  What does this statement  scanf ("%c%*c", &c); mean?

Comment: **while(c == 'c' || c == 'n')** (footnote: is uppercase C or N valid?)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, read the data but don't assign to a variable, in this case it consumes the trailing newline.

Comment: i'll accept any answer too this question i have already what i wanted thank you

Comment: @KeineLust From the C Standard " If there are insufﬁcient arguments for the format, the behavior is undeﬁned."

Comment: Be ware of pesky newline character that gets entered.  It is considered as a character.  To discard a newline character,  `if(c != '\n' ){   ... "`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there are sufficient arguments for the call. The `*` is for assignment suppression.  `%*c` is equivalent to "read and discard one character". No argument need be provided for suppressed specifiers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh, I agree.

Comment: Note that your `"%c%*c"` format only reads and discards the next character. Often, that'll be a newline, as desired, but obstreperous users have been known to type whole words on a line and your code would read the first two characters, discarding the second, and leave the rest behind. You could also use `" %c"` to skip white space, including newlines, and then read a single non-white space character. You should check the return value from `scanf()`; if it does not return 1, you've got problems (almost certainly EOF — end of file; for character inputs, there's not much else can go wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. One, a do-while loop suits your purposes better than an unrolled while loop (equivalent effect, but cleaner-looking). Secondly, your problem is in the conditional, `c != 'c' || c != 'n'` will ALWAYS return true (if it's 'n', it's not 'c', and vice versa); therefore, your loop is infinite. What you mean is `c != 'c' && c != 'n'`

Comment: This **while(c!='c' && c !='n')** would **only** accept a 'c' or 'n' whereas his prompt says enter anything **except** c or n?

Comment: No. A while loop would continue if the letter wasn't a 'c' and wasn't an 'n'. I'm going to get flamed for saying this, but if you're confused about while loops, consider the conditional-jump equivalent:
`while(cond) {stats;}` is the same as `lbl_loop: if(cond) { stats; goto lbl_loop; }`

Comment: My confusion comes from the question **printf("type any character except 'c' or 'n'");** - do they want the loop to continue getting new input if they enter 'c' or 'n' (my understanding), or should it stop if they enter a 'c' or 'n'?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking the latter. In your case, use `c == 'c' || c == 'n'`